# Ionic 2 - Masonry

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, masonry

I have cards in my Ionic2.1 project and I would like to reproduce the masonry like in that js library (http://masonry.desandro.com).
So I would like to know if there is a simple way to do that with ionic2 or should I write something myself.

I tried this AngularJs2 library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-masonry) but didn't managed to make it work.

Thanks in advance for your help.